# Checking parameters for information

Tags: batch-file

I have a Script that reads other .bat Files and counts the Commentlines. I pass the .bat file that i want to test as a parameter.
For example, this is how i start my script.

```
C:\User\User\Desktop>CommentReader.bat test.bat
```

Right now test.bat needs to be in the same folder with the Skript.

I want the option that I can pass multiple .bat files that need testing and the option that I can pass the path too. for example:

```
 C:\User\User\Desktop>CommentReader.bat D:\testfolder\test1.bat E:\test2.bat test3.bat
```

I also want to pass commands for example /l so the script also reads empty lines.

```
C:\User\User\Desktop>CommentReader.bat /l D:\testfolder\test1.bat E:\test2.bat test3.bat
```

I know how I can code that it should also read empty lines but
what is the best way to go through my parameters and check the information?

My Idea was something like this:

```
FOR /f  tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, delims= " %%a in (%*) DO (

)
```

But maybe there is a better way?

Comment: [shift](https://ss64.com/nt/shift.html) and a Goto-Loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Stephan stated in the comments section, `SHIFT` is what you're looking for. This script will loop through all parameters and echo them out. Just replace the `ECHO` command with your actual code.

```
@ECHO OFF
:LOOP
IF NOT "%1"=="" (
    ECHO %1
    SHIFT
    GOTO LOOP
)
```

Your first parameter is always `%1`, the second one is `%2` and so on. The `SHIFT` command will "forget" the original `%1` and decrease all indices by 1, so `%2` will become `%1`, `%3` will become `%2` and so on. As soon as you reach the last argument `SHIFT` will turn `%1` into an empty string so that you beak out of the loop.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll try it out with shift I think that should solve my problem. :D

Comment: Does the SHIFT stay through the whole script or only in the IF query?

Comment: @RjuJBong it holds for the entire script.